# UIDatePicker discards value when hidden during animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I've run into an issue with `UIDatePicker` lately and possibly someone could suggest a solution.

I have a `UIViewController` with `UIDatePicker` as a subview to its view; I show this `UIViewController` in the popover.

The issue is this:
If you select some date quickly and then make popover disappear while picker is still rolling (for instance, by clicking outside of the popover), the date picker won't trigger `UIControlEventValueChanged`.  (won't set the date)

Thus, user should wait for a little till the animation ends, and only after this user should dismiss the popover.

**Some additional details:**

1)
My `UIViewController` with `UIDatePicker` *is not* deallocated after you hide the popover. Date Picker just stops the animation after it goes offscreen.

2)I have tried to do it this way: 
Do not let user to hide popover by clicking outside of it (by providing passthrough views), and using DONE button instead. 
However, unfortunately, this does not solve the problem - it gives more time to this picker to animate while users are clicking 'Done', but some users are still too fast.

3)Unfortunately, `UIDatePicker` does not support neither `UIControlEventEditingDidBegin` / `UIControlEventEditingDidEnd` nor `UIControlEventPrimaryActionTriggered`.

`UIDatePicker` does not seem to have any kind of `isAnimating` property, as well as some kind of 'make user interaction momentary' property.

4)Unfortunately, if you call `[_datePicker date]` during the animation, it will return the value which was before the animation. (e.g. date is not set till `UIDatePicker` finishes animating)

5)UIDatePicker fields, such as 'state' is the same both for animation is going on/not animating:

[[image: UIDatePicker[1]]

Comment: date picker support `ValueChanged` UIControlEvent, You can add a target just like a UIButton, But i don't know if the value is changed, untill the scroll animation is finished

Comment: Hi, it is not - and that's the problem

Comment: that is the default behaviour of UIDatePicker or any UIPicker for that matter

Comment: Yeah. And it makes the usage of UIDatePicker in the popover impossible. Is there any workaround? I don't see the usage of UIDatePicker in popover as some 'weird' decision, it is quite natural, in my opinion..Weird is to have it as a modal (which btw will have the same problem ;) if user discards it too fast)

Comment: BTW, 

In the Apple's standard 'Timer' app the 'Timer' does not have the described problem. If you open the 'Timer' tab and scroll to some value quickly and go to another tab, when you go back to Timer, value is not discarded.


Same in the tab ‘alarms’ - if you edit alarm and go (say) to ‘Repeat’ menu while it is still animating, picker stops immediately! and sets the value. In my case, sometimes I even see how this UIDatePicker stops animation in the middle and animates backwards to the previous value!